# Rails ActiveRecord Database with just one row

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is there a way for a database to only allow one row (e.g. for site-wide settings) ?

Comment: That isn't a database, but you could accomplish something similar with validations. I'm not sure why you would though. Do you expect to *accidentally* insert additional rows?

Comment: No, I just think, if I have a database that should just contain the settings for the site, and I expect it to have only one row, this should also be reflected in the code. Of course, maybe it would be a good idea to use a config file instead of a database - I decided for this approach because that way ActiveRecord takes care of everything, I don't need to store a path to the config file, open/close the file, adress read/write permission issues etc.

Comment: If you're talking about settings that can be configured at runtime, then yes, the database may be appropriate. But the typical Rails convention is to store configuration in the `config/` directory, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :there_can_only_be_one

  private

  def there_can_only_be_one
    errors.add_to_base('There can only be one') if Whatever.count > 0
  end
end
```

Comment: An addtion: In Rails 3, one should use `.errors[:base] << "Msg" ` instead of `.add_to_base("Msg")` ([link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Errors/add_to_base))

Comment: If anybody else wants to use it: This has the down-side that a new Whatever is invalid after saving it, one can fix it via `|| Whatever.first == self` in the condition

Comment: it's `validate`, not `validates`

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 4:

```
class Anything < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :only_one_row

  private
  def only_one_row
    false if Anything.count > 0
  end
end
```

Silent errors are bad, then

```
class Anything < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :only_one_row

  private
  def only_one_row
    raise "You can create only one row of this table" if Anything.count > 0
  end
end
```

Comment: For others who come here instead of 'raise' use the following:

`errors.add(:base, "You can create only one row of this table") if Anything.count > 0`

Answer (score 2):

Is there just one column in this row?  If not, adding new columns with a migration may be overkill.  You could at least make this table contain 'name' and 'value' columns and validate by uniqueness on name.

Comment: Yes, it might, but as written in my comment I want to take the advantages of AR - and I can just add all columns with one migration, which is not a bad thing I suppose. I don't understand how making name-value-columns adresses my question - but Unixmonkey already pointed me to the solution